# Full screen display in portrait/landscape mode in Android

Tags: android

I am using VideoView component for **streaming video in Android**, but I am not getting the **full screen** display.

Kindly provide the code to display full screen in portrait/landscape mode.

Answer (score 3):

modify either your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity  android:name=".YourClassName"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

or your activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // get rid of title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // hide statusbar
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set theme as FullScreen, Hide title bar